# How to control XSLT output formatting for xs:decimal values?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

Is there a way to set a default output formatting for numeric values, specifically to limit the length of the fractional part for xs:decimal?

Example:

```
 <xsl:sequence select="xs:decimal('7.96062992125984252') * xs:decimal('0.33333333')" />
```

On my system, using Saxon-HE 9.7.0.5, the output is:

```
 2.6535432805511811024671916
```

An additional question - I was under the impression xs:decimal is limited to 18 digits for the fractional part, but the above value has 25.

How are xs:decimal values converted for output?

I'd like to limit all values to maximum of 18 digits.

Comment: Not an out-of-the-box-version would be: Write your own function `printDecimal`; Part of the body of this function could be `format-number($decParam, '#.##################')` [rounding is already included]. See `decimal-format` for changing seperator characters (in addition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of digits in xs:decimal is implementation-dependent, with a minimum of 18. Saxon uses arbitrary-precision (the BigDecimal class in Java).

There is no way to change the default decimal-to-string conversion, but you can do an explicit conversion (as opposed to relying on the default conversion) using the format-number function (for example, `format-number($value, '0.00')`.

Incidentally, in XSLT 2.0 a number that looks like an xs:decimal (contains a decimal point and no "e") is an xs:decimal, so your xsl:sequence could be written:

```
<xsl:sequence select="7.96062992125984252 * 0.33333333" />
```

and it would still be doing xs:decimal multiplication.